# MySQL nested join with references to unnested table fields

Tags: mysql, sql, join

These are the (example) tables:

```
first:  id      abc

parent: id  childid  foo
         1        0       -- no  child
         2        1       -- one child

child:  id  abc  bar
         1
         2

last:   id  foo  bar
```

I would like to execute the following query:

```
SELECT
  first.*
 ,parent.*
 ,child.*
 ,last.*

FROM        first  -- actually some joins

-- select exactly 1 `parent` row for each `first` row
-- with an optional `child` row (or NULLs if child.id=0)
LEFT JOIN ( parent
LEFT JOIN   child ON child.id = parent.childid
                 AND child.abc = first.abc <== ERROR HERE
          )       ON parent.childid = 0
                  OR child.id


-- conditions referring to the parent,child rows
LEFT JOIN   last  ON last.foo = parent.foo
                 AND last.bar = child.bar
```

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't like external references in the nested join:
`Unknown column 'first.abc' in 'on clause'`

I would be happy if someone could help me on fixing this type of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Lose those brackets!
2. `ON parent.childid = 0 OR child.id` is invalid. Use `ON parent.childid in (0, child.id)`

It should look like this:

```
...
LEFT JOIN  parent  -- removed opening bracket
LEFT JOIN   child ON child.id = parent.childid
                 AND child.abc = first.abc 
                 AND parent.childid = in (0, child.Id) -- removed closing bracket and used 'IN'
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I try this on my real query.

Comment: Well, the problem is that your query would attach more than one parent row to each 'first' row.

Comment: To be honest, I think your query has questionable value. It is an odd thing indeed to want only one parent. Incidentally, more than one parent means you have a many-to-many, so "parent" is the wrong word, but I would just assign a special foreign key column to your child table that has the key of the "first parent" (whatever that means) and use that to join it up.

Comment: I accepted your answer, because my question really wasn't the best.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT first.*, parent.*, child.*, last.*
FROM first
LEFT JOIN parent ON parent.childid = 0 OR parent.childid IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN child ON child.id = parent.childid AND child.abc = first.abc
LEFT JOIN last  ON last.foo = parent.foo AND last.bar = child.bar
```